What approach do you use to connect SM JST connectors from led strips to a PCB?
I tried to find a PCB solderable connector for SM JST connectors commonly used in led strips like the WS2811. Here's an example of a SM JST connector (image from Digikey):

But I couldn't find any.
I'm trying to build a project that uses an ESP32 soldered on a perfboard on which I could also solder a connector to connect the LED strips and control them. One obvious approach would be to cut the connector and use screw terminals to connect the wires, but I would like if the strip was pluggable.
Is there any other approach that makes the strip pluggable onto a PCB that you would recommend?

Ohmnivore - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page etc. More rules in [tour] & [help]. TY

@SamGibson I've edited the post to add the source of the image (Digikey). The website URL can be found on the image itself because the image is an URL.

Ohmnivore - Thanks. We really want the reference link to go to the webpage that displays the image, and not directly to an image. Linking direct to an external image is not optimal, since if that image disappears (which is outside your control when you link to an image on Digikey's website), then the question becomes useless for future readers. :( Can you provide the link to the product webpage where you copied the image from originally? If not, then I'll try to find it for you, to avoid further issues. TY

Ok, I have added linked text to the product page.

The JST SM connector is exclusively a wire-to-wire connector with crimp terminals. Therefore, it does not have any solderable family members. If you want a wire-to-board connector, then use a wire-to-board connector, not a wire-to-wire connector.
JST makes a few latched wire-to-board connectors with a 2.5 mm pitch (my site). If you're not set on JST, many manufacturers make latched wire-to-board connectors with a 2.5 mm pitch (my site).

Thanks for the information. Is this the way you would recommend (or personally use if you work with led strips) or could there be another approach that you prefer (such as soldering wires onto a board and having a corresponding JST SM connector on the end)?

"soldering wires onto a board and having a corresponding JST SM connector on the end)". If you are dead set on using the JST SM, that's the only solution. And it's an acceptable solution.

Well, I'm not dead set, it's just that they are the connectors that the led strips already come with. I mean, I could crimp other connectors, but if it's an acceptable solution, then I guess I will pick that. Thanks for your help @Davide Andrea
